# Creation of new JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Google Graphs and I am getting data from MySQL database and encoding it with PHP to JSON and sending it from controller to view. But the problem is date is sending as string and graph cannot use this date. And I changed date to unix system and sending it to view I can get date as a date.

```
[[1383424123,"AAA",0.001735],[1383424518,"AAA",0.001689],[1383424123,"BBB",0.65211],[1383424518,"BBB",0.655739],[1383424123,"CCC",1],[1383424518,"CCC",1]]
```

Above I am getting this json object from controller.

In view I am using this json object for Google Graph :

```
<script> var jsonData=<?php echo $jsdata;?> </script>
```

I need to get date unix system values and create new date like ->

```
new Date(jsonData[i][0] * 1000);
```

And create new the same json object but with new date ( will be replaced with  new Date(jsonData[i][0] * 1000); values ) which I am getting from controller and rest of data should remain. How can I do it, creating new json object with replaced date values (only date).

Comment: Just call `new Date(jsonData[i][0] * 1000); ` again? I don't think I understand the problem. Note that this has nothing to do with JSON, because inside the JavaScript source code, the PHP output is treated as an array literal.

Comment: I am getting this json object and I need to get it in view and create a new date and replace with unix date in json object

Comment: Is it possibe, create an empty json object, go with loop into jsonData and replace unix date something like this -> new Date(jsonData[i][0] * 1000);

Comment: Oh, sure, you don't even have to create a new array. Just iterate over it and do `jsonData[i][0] = new Date(jsonData[i][0] * 1000);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just modify the existing value of the array by assigning back to it:

```
jsonData[i][0] = new Date(jsonData[i][0] * 1000);.
```